# Using twilio-chat with react-native

Tags: react-native, twilio

I'm trying to use twilio-chat with react-native, I manage to use it on ios and on android when remote debugger is active but when I use android with no debugger I can't init Client.

Did someone manage to use it?

this is the impofrtant part of the code:

```
import { Client } from 'twilio-chat';

this.client = await Client.create(chatToken).catch(err => this.onChatLoadFailed(err));
if (!this.client) return this.onChatLoadFailed(this.client);
this.channels = await loadChannels();
```

and a part of warning logs

```
TwilsockError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false
TwilsockUpstreamError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false
```

with external debugger there is no problem so I'd like to make it work without V8 engine that the debugger has.